# What's the difference between spark.sql() and spark.read.format("jdbc").option("query", "")?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I assumed that spark.sql(query) is used when we are using spark sql and that  spark.read.format("jdbc").option("query", "") is used when we are using oracle sql syntax. Would I be right in assuming so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and Spark does more than that too!

**`Spark-Jdbc:`**

[From Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) Jdbc(Java Database connectivity) is used to **read/write data** from other databases (oracle, mysql, sqlserver, postgres, db2..etc).

`spark.read.format("jdbc").option("query", "(select * from <db>.<tb>)e")`

**`Spark-Sql:`**

[From docs](https://spark.apache.org/sql/) Spark's module for working with structured data and lets you to query data using **DataFrame API** or [**SQL API**](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-spark-sql).

1. We can use Spark-Sql to read data from hive/presto/athena/delta/csv/parquet...etc files.
2. Create a temporary view/table on dataframe then run SQL queries.
3. [Easily](https://databricks.com/glossary/what-is-spark-sql) write RDD's/Dataframes to Hive or Parquet files.

[image]